# How I run a method after select a item in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a form to register users and I have two dropdowns one for state and another for city. I want that the user can select a state and from that state populate the second dropdown with cities from this state. I have an API to do that but I dont know how to activate the metod when I select a state. That's a SPA and I'm rendering the pages on my *"top.js"* class.

**Methods to get the API**

```
estados = () => {
        let dropdown = document.getElementById('estadodrop');
        dropdown.length = 0;

        let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
        defaultOption.text = 'Selecione seu Estado';

        dropdown.add(defaultOption);
        dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

        const url = 'https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/';

        fetch(url)
            .then(
                function (response) {
                    if (response.status !== 200) {
                        console.warn('Erro: ' +
                            response.status);
                        return;
                    }

                    response.json().then(function (data) {
                        let option;

                        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            option = document.createElement('option');
                            option.text = data[i].nome;
                            dropdown.add(option);
                            let ufid = data[i].id;

                        }

                    });
                }
            )
    }

    cidades = (ufid) => {
        let dropdown = document.getElementById('cidadedrop');
        dropdown.length = 0;

        let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
        defaultOption.text = 'Selecione sua Cidade';

        dropdown.add(defaultOption);
        dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

        const url = "https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidade/estados/" + ufid + "/distritos";

        fetch(url)
            .then(
                function (response) {
                    if (response.status !== 200) {
                        console.warn('Erro: ' +
                            response.status);
                        return;
                    }

                    response.json().then(function (data) {
                        let option;

                        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            option = document.createElement('option');
                            option.text = data[i].nome;
                            option.value = ufselecionada
                            dropdown.add(option);

                        }
                    });
                }
            )
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.error('Erro do fetch:', err);
            });
    }
```

**My top.js**

```
import { Cliente } from "./Cliente.js";

export class Topo {

    constructor(){
        this.render();
    }
    render = () => { 
        let topo = document.getElementById("topo");
        topo.innerHTML = "<p id='pCadastroCliente'><a href='#'>Cadastrar Cliente</a></p>"+
        "<br> <p id='pClientes'><a href='#'>Clientes Cadastrados</a></p>";
        let p = document.createElement("p");
        topo.append(p);

        let pCadastrarCliente = document.getElementById('pCadastroCliente');

        let cliente = new Cliente();

        pCadastrarCliente.addEventListener( "click", () =>{
            cliente.renderCadastro();
            cliente.estados();
        });

        let pClientesCadastrados = document.getElementById('pClientes');

        pClientesCadastrados.addEventListener( "click", () => {
             cliente.renderListar();
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to be listening to the onchange event for the dropdown, not the onclick event. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Comment: **I tried this way but I'm getting a error message:**
```pCadastrarCliente.addEventListener( "click", () =>{
            cliente.renderCadastro();
            cliente.estados();
        });

        let dropCidades = document.getElementById('estadodrop');

        dropCidades.addEventListener("onchange", () =>{
            cliente.cidades();
        })
```

**The error returned:** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Go ahead and debug - find out why the object you're trying to run addEventListener() on is null. Probably because the selector you're using for it is incorrect.